# How should I implement lag compensation in my racing game?

Tags: server, interpolation, racing, lag, client

I've looked around and I see a lot of discussion about lag compensation for FPS's, but none for racing games.

I know Mario Kart uses some sort of interpolation for other racers, but it doesn't provide very smooth results a lot of the times, when the simulated kart goes way off course and then teleports back on track with the next server update. I think games like Forza also use interpolation, but the cars in games like that move a lot more predictably, so it doesn't seem noticeable.

If I'm going for a game with the same type of chaotic movement that of Mario Kart, will I just have to accept that there will be sudden visible teleporting when a player has a bad connection to the server?